# How can an anonymous editor introduce profanity into a question?

Tags: discussion

An "anonymous" edit with profanities [just appears out of the blue](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5757), how is it possible?

Comment: And @Dheer, did you really approve it???

Comment: It looks like @Dheer thought he was approving an edit to *remove* the profanity, not add it.

Comment: It was misleading, When I saw the original post and saw, the edit summary had profanity, and i tried improving it and removing it, I guess I goofed up and hence flagged to Moderator attention.

Comment: But how does it happen, these "anonymous" edits?

Comment: Using the *"improve this question"* or *"improve this answer"* links that you'd see if you were an anonymous (not logged in) user.  Such edits enter a review queue that require somebody with sufficient rep to approve.

Comment: @littleadv the question isn't how did it happen, but how have we been so fortunate that it rarely does. In two years, I think I've rejected a similar edit only once.

Comment: @Chris that answered my question, thanks:) Didn't know there's an option of posting without registering

Answer (score 4):

I assume bots do it all the time, but I have also seen the occasional SEO expert stop by just to add links.

**Bot:**

https://money.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5703

**Search Engine Optimizer consultancy:**

https://money.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5693

That is why we have to take our time in that review queue.